# Are there any major risks to running a windows service as the login user?

Tags: windows, windows-services, efs

Are there any risks to running a service as the admin (and login) user on a Windows 10 machine? For instance, will the password be stored on disk in a manner accessible to someone with physical access to the machine? Obviously there is the risk that the service may run code as the user, too, but I don't know if that would be worse than running as SYSTEM.

As for why I'd *want* to do this, I have several hundred gigabytes of files encrypted with [EFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypting_File_System), and I would like to back up these files. This requires that the backup service be able to read the files, which it cannot due to the SYSTEM user not having the appropriate certificate. Adding the certificate for the SYSTEM user to these files would be rather suboptimal, as that certificate is essentially not encrypted at rest - which then removes any protection EFS might provide. Running the backup service as the user in question allows access to the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying a user account for running a system service requires specifying
the password.

The account data is stored as
[LSA Private Data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secmgmt/storing-private-data)
in the registry under key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY\Policy\Secrets\_SC_<ServiceName>`.
Access to this key is rigidly controlled and is not easy and the data is also
encrypted. It is impossible to access even for administrators.

Nevertheless, the data can be hacked, although only by a very knowledgeable person.
See for a forensic treatment the article of
[Use PowerShell to Decrypt LSA Secrets from the Registry](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-decrypt-lsa-secrets-from-the-registry/).

My personal opinion is that the protection is good and the password is safe enough.
If anyone with that much knowledge manages to gain that level of control
over your setup, then service passwords are the least of your worries.